# Ext JS grid display multiple headers

Tags: php, extjs, grid

I'd like to display an Ext JS grid with multiple headers every x number of rows like:

```
[ID | Name | Value]
001|John  | 10,000
002|Amy   | 15,000
[ID | Name | Value]
003|Mike  | 5,000
004|Lisa  | 45,000
```

Where the ID, name and value row is the header.

I like to know if this at all possible. I have checked the base examples but couldn't find anything about it, only grouped data, and that didn't seem like the solution for my problem.
And if it is possible could you possible show me an example of how I would use this.

The only solution I could think of is splitting the data in the backend and building a grid for each piece of data, but that seems like a long shot.

I'm using both Ext JS version 3.2.1 and 4.1 because we're still transfering from version 3.2.1 to 4.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following solution http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146348-ExtJS-4-Grid-Printer-Plugin to print the page with multiple headers.

The one thing I changed was

```
'<tr>',
  headings,
'</tr>',
```

into

```
'<thead>',
  headings,
'</thead>',
```

And added this to css to display the header on each printed page (works in FireFox and IE9):

```
thead { 
    display: table-header-group; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible just through simple configuration. You'll need to override the `Ext.panel.Table` & `Ext.view.Table` classes and modify the mark up for the table to do this. It'll be enormous effort. As an alternative I can suggest either checking the `headerPosition` config or setting a paging toolbar with a suitable `pageSize` like so:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: 50,
        model: 'ForumThread',
        remoteSort: true,
        proxy: {
            // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
            // this page, an HttpProxy would be better
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php',
            reader: {
                root: 'topics',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            },
            // sends single sort as multi parameter
            simpleSortMode: true
        },
        sorters: [{
            property: 'lastpost',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }]
    });
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        //other config
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
            items:[
                '-', {
                text: 'Show Preview',
                pressed: pluginExpanded,
                enableToggle: true,
                toggleHandler: function(btn, pressed) {
                    var preview = Ext.getCmp('gv').getPlugin('preview');
                    preview.toggleExpanded(pressed);
                }
            }]
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the your quick response. I have indeed seen the paging example, unfortunately I want all the data on the same page, because I'm printing the data on paper / PDF and want a header on every page so I know what data I'm reading.
I'll try the header config though and the alternative I'll keep in my, although I'd rather not do that.

Comment: For pdf generation, it's best to do it server side with a library (for  example, for java/c# you can use apache poi) and send the response back to the client as a `application/pdf` header. For direct printing you could use the store and generate your own html mark up and print the data in tabular format.